# The difference between onErrorResume and onErrorReturn

Tags: java, reactor

In spring project reactor, what are the differences between onErrorResume and onErrorReturn ? and when I should each of them ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Your question is too broad as it would just be quoting the javadoc of these methods. What exactly is the problem you have with these methods and what exactly do you not understand how they work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

onErrorReturn => use case in the scenario of static default value.

Ex:

```
 public Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        return sayHello(request)
          .onErrorReturn("Hello Stranger")
          .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.ok()
          .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
          .syncBody(s));
    }
```

onErrorResume- has multiple use cases

- Compute a dynamic fallback value
- Execute an alternative path with a fallback method
  -Catch, wrap, and re-throw an error e.g. as a custom
  business exception

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors) tutorial has examples for each scenarios.