# Reactive Mono not propagating Custom Exception

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

In our service calling function `getXXResponse` where `XX` is API partner returning Mono.
Just in case of success and `mono.error` in case of error.

Below is a snippet from code:

```java
    void abc() throws CustomException{
       Mono<String> response = getXXResponse();
    
       response.subscribe(
             res-> {
                   .....logic in success case
             },
             throwable-> {
                  logger.info("in throwable callback");
                  throw new CustomException("ERROR");
             }
       );
    
       Hooks.onErrorDropped(error ->{
          logger.info("in hook");
          throw new CustomException("ERROR");
       });
    
     }
    
    }
```

After running the code, it's printing:

```
in throwable callback  

In Hook
In Hook
In Hook
In Hook
In Hook
In Hook
Error reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler - Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.
```

But throwing `Exception` to parent method.
I want to return/propagate exception to parent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at "**[How to handle errors in Reactive Spring webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67531829/6309)**", in a reactive stream, you should not throw exceptions directly in the way you would in imperative code. Exceptions are intended to be propagated in a non-blocking way through the stream's error channel.

Throwing an exception in the [`onError` handler](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling)  or in [`Hooks.onErrorDropped`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#hooks-dropping) would be like throwing an exception in a catch block without catching it. It will not be handled by the reactive stream, and instead it will be thrown on the thread executing this part of the pipeline, which is not what you want.

In a reactive world, everything is non-blocking and handled by the framework, including exceptions. Exceptions should not be thrown, but rather returned to the pipeline so that Project Reactor can handle them properly.

To propagate an exception to the parent, you should use the `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResume` operator in your reactive stream. These operators allow you to return a fallback value or another `Mono`/`Flux` when an error occurs.
See also "[**Handling Errors in Spring WebFlux**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors)", and "**[The difference between onErrorResume and onErrorReturn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64849989/6309)**"

```java
Mono<String> response = getXXResponse();

response
    .doOnNext(res -> {
        // logic in success case
    })
    .doOnError(throwable -> {
        logger.info("in throwable callback");
    })
    .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
        // Catch the original error, wrap it in a custom exception, 
        // and throw the custom exception as an error signal.
        return Mono.error(new CustomException("ERROR"));
    })
    .subscribe();
```

`onErrorResume` will catch the error and then propagate your `CustomException` to the upstream as an error signal.
If the exception should be handled in the parent method, you need to subscribe to the `Mono` in the parent method, not in the method where it is created.
If not, the exception is thrown on the thread where `subscribe()` is called and the `Mono` is executed, and it will not propagate to the parent method.